# Парсинг данных уничтоженных таблиц из ворд

Tags: python, c, парсер, excel, xmlparser

Стоит задача распарсить docx минприроды, который их машина уничтожила, в таблицу хорошего качества со всеми нюансами, чтобы потом тягачами брать инфу и тянуть к серверу. Дорогие форумчане, бьюсь уже с задачей 1-2 недели на Python, но у меня не выходит. Подскажите инструменты или другой язык или скрипт какой. Исходный вид docx будет первой фотографией, необходимый вид excel формата вторая фотография [image: такой исходный формат док файла, видно структуру и тд, но не понимаю как это собирать в таблицу]  [image: необходимый формат, который правильно распределен по колонкам, который можно тянуть]  Любые идеи и подсказки приветствуются!

Comment: Верхняя картинка это txt файл?

Comment: Если txt, то открываете в Excel и он сам распознает колонки. Дальше можно отсортировать и удалить строки "итого"

Comment: верхняя txt, занося ее в Excel получается полный бред, бьет строки со словами и тд криво, таких строк у меня 10000+, поэтому данный метод не подходит

Comment: Не копировать в Эксель, а открыть этот файл. Файл\Открыть\ выбрать все файлы.